# QGIS Process Modeler: Create Algorithm to update feature count in Layers Panel

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis-3

I have a little Python script which I want to use, in order to update the feature counts of all layers in the Layers Panel by reloading them.
I want to use this algorithm in the QGIS Graphical Process Modeler after I did some stuff on the database, to get the correct feature count at the end of the entire process. The core algorithm looks like this and it works perfectly when executed from the Python Console:

```
from qgis.utils import iface

QgsProject.instance().reloadAllLayers()
iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
```

I "only" need to place this into the correct Python Script format so that it properly registers in the QGIS Processing Toolbox in the "Scripts" section.
I modified the QGIS template script and this version finally works now:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
***************************************************************************
*                                                                         *
*   This algorithm is updating the feature count in the Layers Panel      *
*                                                                         *
***************************************************************************
"""

from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                       QgsFeatureSink,
                       QgsProcessingException,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink,
                       QgsProject)
from qgis import processing
from qgis.utils import iface


class UpdateFeatureCount(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    """
    This algorithm updates the feature count in the Layers Panel.
    """

    # Constants used to refer to parameters and outputs. They will be
    # used when calling the algorithm from another algorithm, or when
    # calling from the QGIS console.

    def tr(self, string):
        """
        Returns a translatable string with the self.tr() function. 
        """
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

    def createInstance(self):
        return UpdateFeatureCount()

    def name(self):
        """
        Returns the algorithm name, used for identifying the algorithm. This
        string should be fixed for the algorithm, and must not be localised.
        The name should be unique within each provider. Names should contain
        lowercase alphanumeric characters only and no spaces or other
        formatting characters.
        """
        return 'updatefeaturecountinlayerpanel'

    def displayName(self):
        """
        Returns the translated algorithm name, which should be used for any
        user-visible display of the algorithm name.
        """
        return self.tr('Update Feature Count in Layers Panel')

    def group(self):
        """
        Returns the name of the group this algorithm belongs to. This string
        should be localised.
        """
        return self.tr('scripts')

    def groupId(self):
        """
        Returns the unique ID of the group this algorithm belongs to. This
        string should be fixed for the algorithm, and must not be localised.
        The group id should be unique within each provider. Group id should
        contain lowercase alphanumeric characters only and no spaces or other
        formatting characters.
        """
        return 'scripts'

    def shortHelpString(self):
        """
        Returns a localised short helper string for the algorithm. This string
        should provide a basic description about what the algorithm does and the
        parameters and outputs associated with it..
        """
        return self.tr("Algorithm to update the feature count in the Layers Panel")

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        """
        Here we define the inputs and output of the algorithm, along
        with some other properties.
        """

        # We add the input vector features source. It can have any kind of
        # geometry.

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        """
        Here is where the processing itself takes place.
        """
        QgsProject.instance().reloadAllLayers()
        # you need to loop throught the existing layers in the project
        # and then refreshLayerSymbology
        layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()
        for layer in layers:
            iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
        return {}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
    QgsProject.instance().reloadAllLayers()
    # you need to loop throught the existing layers in the project
    # and then refreshLayerSymbology
    layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()
    for layer in layers:
        iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
    return {self}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'm looping now through the layers while refreshing LayerSymbology but I get a new error message which I have never seen before. A small pop-up window appears saying: "TypeError: invalid result from UpdateFeatureCount.processAlgorithm(), set cannot be converted to a C/C++ QVariantMap in this context ". I have no clue what this means. 

Note I updated the original post to show the current Python code.

Comment: it seems like the processAlgorithm function need to return a dict containing the result, like 
`{'OUTPUT': something}` 
you can refer to the following [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/312673/pyqgis-plugin-returns-error-from-processalgorithm-invalid-result/312687)